# Unrecognized Expression in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to pass checkbox that already checked into ajax but I keep getting this error
`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .[object HTMLInputElement]:checked`

I think the syntax could be wrong but I don't know.
Here is my code.

```
        $(".category").on('click', function(){
            var category = get_filter(this);
            var sort = $("#sort option:selected").text();
            var url = $(location).attr('href');

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: 'POST',
                data: {category:category, sort:sort, url:url},
                success: function(data){
                    // console.log(data);
                    alert(category);
                }
            })
        });

        function get_filter(class_name){
            var filter = [];
            $('.'+class_name+":checked").each(function(){
                filter.push($(this).val());
            });

            return filter;

        }
```

Comment: `this` refers to the `HTMLInputElement` instance, it is _not_ the class name in string form. You need to _read_ the class from this element first, if you want to pass only that to `get_filter`.

Comment: You pass **`this`** which is a DOM element into `get_filter()`, but `get_filter` seems to expect a string. The expression `'.'+class_name+":checked"` will execute as `'.' + class_name.toString() + ":checked"`, where `class_name.toString()` produces "[object HTMLInputElement]". And then the result of the expression is `.[object HTMLInputElement]:checked`.

Comment: ah i see.. i should get the class name first then pass it into `class_name` so `this` will read the class name, right